# WPF creating grid from XAML in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, wrappanel

I have an empty grid with no data but with all the columns in the XAML - is there way to create multiple of these grids in the code-behinds ie .cs file

I know how to create new grids in the code-behind but not existing grids...any ideas?

Thanks
Ram

Comment: What do you mean by creating Grid which already exists? How can you create something that already exists?

Comment: I want to create multiple copies of a grid that already exists on the XAML page...it is empty with no data...if user enters 5..it should create 5 of those grids...hope this makes sense...

Comment: and how do you want to position them? Next to each other?

Comment: Yes they should be next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by making your "existing grid" a separate `UserControl`.

First, you need to add a `UserControl` via [Add]->[User Control...]->[User Control (WPF)].

Next, put your "existing grid" inside the added `UserControl`.

YourExistingGridControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Your.Namespace.YourExistingGridControl">
  <Grid>
     ... YOUR EMPTY GRID WITH ALL THE COLUMNS, ETC. ...
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, you can create as many instances of that "existing grid" as you like.

YourCodeBehind.xaml.cs

```
private void AddYourExistingGrid()
{
  var myGrid = new Your.Namespace.YourExistingGridControl();

  yourWrapPanel.Children.Add(myGrid);
}
```