# How can I instantiate complex group of controls and acces to their values? (wpf with visual studio)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to implement a list of programmatically instanced group of controls such as this one:
[Example of my group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7ryN.jpg)
.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBox_Data"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBox_Time"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock_ID"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Type"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button_Data"/>
<Grid/>
```

It contains 2 TextBox, 1 TextBlock and 1 ComboBox and 1 button ( detail is pretty irrelevant tough) inside a Grid.

I would like to duplicate the Grid Parent to fill a list, and access to every values of the duplicated controls but I can not figure out how to do this.

I had in mind something equivalent to Android Studio java/xml combo but I couldn't find anything on this topic around here.

Any lead is more than welcome.

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: have you tried creating a contenttemplate for listview`s listviewItems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate `UserControl` that contains your group of controls.

Do something similar to this:

[WPF creating grid from XAML in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499763/wpf-creating-grid-from-xaml-in-code-behind/43519245)

But, instead of code-behind, you can reference your new `UserControl` in a XAML.

Comment: I'm trying that! Thanks :)